# Use loop and xchg instruction in assembly language to swap the element in the array

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, x86, masm

I am having a course about assembly language, and I bump into this question which is use the loop and xchg instruction to swap all of the element in the array
the array look like this
The inputStr contains these element “A”, “B”, “C”, “D”, “E”, “F”, “G”, “H”.
And after use the loop and xchg, it has to look like this “G”, “H”, “E”, “F”, “C”, “D”, “A”, “B”.

I have already tried to do it many times, but my output is not right. I cannot figure out the logic, or the right way to do this.

This is my code and it is in x86

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.data
    inputStr BYTE "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"

.code
main PROC
    mov ecx, 8
    xor ebx, ebx
    mov ebx, offset inputStr


    l1:
       xor eax, eax
       mov al, [ebx]
       add ebx, ecx
       sub ebx, 2
       xchg al, [ebx]
       add ebx, 1
       sub ebx, ecx
       xchg al, [ebx]
       inc ebx
       dec ecx
   
       loop l1


    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: So they want you to reverse it in 2-byte chunks.  Seems like `word ptr [ebx]` operand-size would be most useful.  `xchg` isn't normally useful for that, normally you'd do 2 loads then 2 stores from opposite registers.  But you could do load / xchg (as load+store) / store if you don't care about efficiency.  (`xchg [mem], reg` has an implicit `lock` prefix, so it's much slower, doing an atomic RMW and full memory barrier.)

Comment: Can you do it on paper i.e. do you have an algorithm independent of assembly?

Comment: The `loop` instruction already decrements `ecx` so, are you sure you want to `dec` separately?

Comment: What's up with your random changes to EBX?  Like `sub ebx, 2` and `add ebx, 1` / `inc ebx`.  Use `[ebx - 2]` in an addressing mode for small constant offsets.  Or perhaps `[ecx+ebx - 2]` vs. `[ebx + 1]`?  Hard to track without comments when you do it in this clunky way.  I guess you're trying to start from the outsides and work in towards the middle, swapping pairs of bytes?  And you're doing an extra decrement of ECX so you're doing `do{}while(ecx-=2  != 0)`?  That would fail for odd lengths, so normally you'd want `sub ecx,2` / `jge l1`.

Comment: What actually happens when you run your code?  your [mcve] omits the actual result.  Does it just reverse the array by bytes instead of words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an array with N elements, for reversing purposes you can perform N/2 swaps. And if you pair up the elements it's like you started with an array of (N/2) elements, so the number of swaps becomes (N/2)/2.

Apparantly you are required to use the `loop` and `xchg` instructions. Both are notably slow, so there's also no reason to use the better `movzx` in next code:

```
   mov  ecx, (8 / 2) / 2        ; Number of swaps
   mov  ebx, offset inputStr
T1:
   mov  ax, [ebx]               ; Reading a pair
   xchg ax, [ebx + ecx * 4 - 2] ; Swapping a pair
   mov  [ebx], ax               ; Writing a pair
   add  ebx, 2
   loop T1
```

What the iterations actually do:

```
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"
        <---------------- 8 ----------------->
ECX=2   "G", "H", "C", "D", "E", "F", "A", "B"
        ^                             ^
        EBX                           EBX + 2 * 4 - 2
                                            ^
                                            ECX

        "G", "H", "C", "D", "E", "F", "A", "B"
                  <------ 4 ------->
ECX=1   "G", "H", "E", "F", "C", "D", "A", "B"
                  ^         ^
                  EBX       EBX + 1 * 4 - 2
                                  ^
                                  ECX

ECX=0
```

Answer (score 0):

In 64-bit, it could be as simple as:

```
ITEMS = 8
inputList WORD "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"

    mov rbx, inputList
    mov ecx, ITEMS/2/2
@@:
    mov eax, [rbx]
    xchg [rbx+rcx*8-4], eax
    mov [rbx], eax

    add rbx, 4
    loop @B
```

It just produces the desired result by XCHG'ing pairs of 2-byte elements.

From this you should be able to construct the 16-bit variant quite easily using AX instead of RAX.

Comment: The OP's array is of `BYTE` elements, not DWORDs, so they only need `word ptr` operand-size, not qword.  Which is good because they're writing 32-bit code.

Comment: I answered the algorithmic question without doing the OP's homework. Hopefully, there is still learning taking place if OP is serious about learning assembly. Obviously, I can produce a solution - right?

Comment: "Obviously, I can produce a solution - right?" Your code does not produce the desired result! It will give : "G", "H", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"